To remove the oracle home or not
We have all of our DBs on Exadata's in Oracle 19. For some reason one of the other DBAs installed an Oracle 18 home and it never gets used or patched. Our security office keeps flagging it since it is out of date. Being that it is not being used and is just a bunch of binaries is there a security risk involved here by just leaving it? It seems to be the discussion we are having and no one has a technical answer as to whether is or not.  If it is  a security risk how is it one?

Apart from this being off-topic here (perhaps [infosec.se]?), why do you care? Why do you want to keep it if it's not being used?
